# linq to sharepoint and excessive cpu usage issue

Tags: linq

our project is using linq to sharepoint , its working well the only problem we are facing is the extra CPU usage its taking , even if only two or three users  concurrently accesses the local testing server on which the application is deployed , the cpu consumption shoots up to 100% and it takes about a good 20 to 30 seconds until it gets back to normalcy , this is only ocurring when we are acessing the module that uses linq to sharepoint for data access , the application is behaving alright otherwise

the local testing server's specification
8gb ram  core i3

Comment: are you sure that linq to sharepoint is causing the load? what are the reasons that you thinkt that linq2sp is responsible for this?

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you're using LINQ to SharePoint you should look at any CAML which is generated from queries (see [How to: View CAML Generated by LINQ to SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798464.aspx)). Because if Linq2SP can't figure out how to generate a proper CAML it'll silently generate a limited CAML returning way more data than needed and not sorted and then do further selection and sorting in memory.

One of the examples I've see is selecting top ten items with a certain choice column value sorted by a field being turned into return all items, and then do the rest in memory.